# js loop through clicked elements childnodes

Tags: javascript, loops, child-nodes

js loop through clicked elements childnodes
and i have error : 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined

I need to compare if one of them have class task-value
and i cant understand why i have the error!!!
Need Help sorry for bad English
Link to js fiddle whith code

[Link to code on js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guntarwi/wob4kjp2/1/)

```
function docClick(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    console.log(this.childNodes.length)

    for(var i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++){
        console.log(this.childNodes[i])

        if(this.childNodes[i].classList.contains("task-value")){
            console.log("if")
        }else{
            console.log("else")
        }
    }
```

[Link UpDate whit full css/Html and Javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/Guntarwi/wob4kjp2/2/)

Comment: No `html` appears at linked jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This become possible because `this.childNodes` contains not only HTML elements but `text` nodes too. Text nodes can't have classes so them never have property `classList`
You need to use property `children` to get exactly `html elements`

```
function docClick(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    console.log(this.children.length)

    for(var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++){
        console.log(this.children[i])

        if(this.children[i].classList.contains("task-value")){
            console.log("if")
        }else{
            console.log("else")
        }
    }
```